# How to make some chemformula bonds bold?

Tags: chemistry, chemformula

I'm making an IR wavenumber table. One of the bonds is the C-H of an alkyne, and I want to emphasize the `C-H` bond *only*. I tried to make just the C-H bond bold, keeping the triple bond untouched. There's the option

```
\setchemformula{bond-style=thick}
```

but it changes every single bond. Or maybe there's another way of emphazising the `C-H` bond in `\ch{C+C-H}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
Not bold: $\mathrm{C\equiv C-H}$

Bold: $\mathrm{C\equiv C\bm{-}H}$%looks like it, but not thick enough

\ch{C+C-H}%normal style

\setchemformula{bond-style=thick}

\ch{C+C-H}%every bond is now thick

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Please provide an MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new bond type `singleemph` can be defined and used. Also other properties like color can be changed, see section "6.5 Bonds" in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula_en.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\DeclareChemBond{singleemph}{
  \draw[chembond, thick, red]
    (chemformula-bond-start) -- (chemformula-bond-end)
  ;
}

\begin{document}

\ch{C+C\bond{singleemph}H}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Options can also be inserted in the middle of the formula, see "7.2 Option  Input" in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula_en.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
  \ch{C+C @{bond-style={thick,red}} -H}
\end{document}
```